# i am not able to create a bean and i cant plug my controller to service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleUrlHandlerMapping' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.mobicule.LoginController] for bean with name 'toLoginController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobicule.LoginController
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.mobicule.LoginController] for bean with name 'toLoginController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobicule.LoginController
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.mobicule.ServiceImplementation] for bean with name 'toServiceImplementation' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobicule.ServiceImplementation
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.mobicule.DaoImplementaion] for bean with name 'edao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobicule.DaoImplementaion
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.mobicule.LoginController] for bean with name 'toLoginController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobicule.LoginController
```

Comment: Only showing the error is a little hard to solve the problem, it's better to show other related codes also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is self-explanatory:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [com.mobicule.LoginController] for bean with name
>   'toLoginController' defined in ServletContext

In your spring context there's no instance of `com.mobicule.LoginController`
You should add it either using XML:

```
<bean class="com.mobicule.LoginController"/>
```

Or add a [@Component](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) annotation to it if you are using configuration with annotations